# Find permutation matrix that minimizes a Frobenius norm

Tags: matrices, optimization, permutations, discrete-optimization, permutation-matrices

Is there an efficient way to solve (maybe approximately) the following optimization problem

$$\left\| A - X B X^T \right \|_F \xrightarrow[]{X}\min$$

where $X$ is a permutation matrix and $A$, $B$ are dense square symmetric real matrices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An algorithm for this problem could be used to solve the graph isomorphism problem- let $B_{i,j}$ be 0 or 1 depending on whether or not edge $(i,j)$ is in graph $B$, and let $A_{i,j}$ be 0 or 1 depending on whether or not edge $(i,j)$ is in graph $A$.  The two graphs are isomorphic if and only if there is a solution to your problem with Frobenius norm 0.

It's true that that graph isomorphism is solvable in quasi-polynomial time, but that algorithm is of more theoretical than practical interest.

Your problem is more general than the graph isomorphism problem, so I would expect it to be difficult in practice for large instances.  If I had to solve it exactly for small instances, I'd probably try to develop a branch and bound algorithm.  I'd try a local search heuristic for larger instances.

Comment: It also can be cast to Markov Random Field optimization problem and algorithms specialized for MRFs can be used. But thank you for providing higher level view to this problem, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is equivalent to:

$$\text{minimize} \quad  \|A-XBX^T\|_F^2=\|A\|_F^2-2\langle A,XBX^T\rangle+\|XBX^T\|_F^2$$

which is equivalent to:

$$\text{minimize} \quad  -\langle A,XBX^T\rangle = -\text{trace}(X^TA^TXB)$$

The latter is due to $\|A\|_F^2$ and $\|XBX^T\|_F^2$ are constants.

This problem is the [quadratic assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_assignment_problem) and is NP-hard, with a special case being the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).