# Find the best permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, permutations

I have two known square matrices, $A$ and $B$, of the same dimensions. My objective is to find a permutation matrix $P$ that minimizes the Frobenius norm of the difference between $PAP$ and $B$,

$$\|PAP - B\|_F$$
​
Is this problem related — or can it be converted — to another well-known optimization problem for which an efficient algorithm is available? If not, is exhaustive search the only possible approach?

Can  the problem be simplified if $P$ is a symmetric matrix，

Comment: Could probably do a MIP formulation of this?

Comment: I don't know how to answer this in either case, but I'm surprised by the setup: in what context do we want $PAP$ instead of $PAP^{-1}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884318/find-permutation-matrix-that-minimizes-a-frobenius-norm